# How do I hide everything except a div and all of its children?

Tags: css

I'd like to hide all of the content on a page except for on specific div containing `class="content-container"` when printing a webpage.

My markup now is:

```
@media print {
 :not(.content-container) {
  display: none!important;
 }
}
```

Now when I try to print the page nothing is visible, also the div isn't. I think I need to select like everything that is not a child of `.content-container` but don't know how.

Does somebody know how to target everything but that div and it's children?

Comment: the parent(s) of that div has to be visible else it will be hidden too. Your selector is too short ... it will start setting html to display:none; from there, all is hidden.

Comment: Why don't you add a class (e.g. .np) to all elements (parents) you don't want to be printed?

Comment: I can't change the parents unfortunately, but thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **N.B.** This solution only works if `.content-container` is, itself, *not* a child of another element.

You will be able to achieve this effect by applying `display: none` to every element on the page and then *over-riding* that `display` specifically for `.content-container` and its children.

---

**Example:**

```
@media print {

  /* APPLY DISPLAY:NONE TO EVERYTHING */
  * {
    display: none;
  }

  /* OVERRIDE DISPLAY:NONE FOR .CONTENT-CONTAINER AND ITS CHILDREN */

  html,
  body,
  .content-container,
  .content-container * {
    display: initial;
  }

}
```

---

### Where `.content-container` is a child of `main`

If `.content-container` is consistently a child of `main`, the same effect should be relatively easy to achieve with the following style rules:

```
html,
body,
main,
main .content-container,
.content-container * {
display: initial;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
* {
  display: none;
}

html,
body,
main,
main .content-container,
.content-container * {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>ABC</header>

<main>
  <h2>DEF</h2>
  <article class="content-container">
    <p>GHI</p>
    <p>JKL</p>
  </article>
</main>

<aside>
  <p>MNO</p>
<aside>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>PQR</li>
    <li>STU</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately content-container is a child of a main container aswell. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @Sybrentjuh - No worries. Have a look at the second approach above. That should give you the tools you need to put something together which addresses the specifics of your markup.

Comment: Ah this is cool and looks like it's working. Thanks!!